# What is the algorithmic complexity of this sorting function?

Tags: python, sorting, complexity-theory

I devised the following sorting algorithm while playing with Legos, based on the idea of always stacking smaller pieces on top of bigger pieces until you come across a piece that doesn't fit on either end of the stack.

My initial impression is that its best-case behavior is O(n) and its worst-case behavior is O(n^2) since it's similar to strand sort, but it's been so long since I've done algorithmic analysis in college that I have no idea what its average behavior is. It looks like it ought to be better than strand sort's average O(n^2), but I don't know how to prove it or what it is.

My implementation uses a linked list to allow insertions on both ends, but a deque would work just as well. The following is Python code for convenience of description, but the C++ version is more efficient.

```
import math

def merge(x, y):
    output = []
    xp = 0
    yp = 0
    if len(y) == 0 or len(x) == 0 or y[0] > x[-1]:
        return x + y
    elif x[0] > y[-1]:
        return y + x
    while xp < len(x) and yp < len(y):
        if x[xp] < y[yp]:
            output.append(x[xp])
            xp = xp + 1
        else:
            output.append(y[yp])
            yp = yp + 1
    if xp < len(x):
        output = output + x[xp:]
    elif yp < len(y):
        output = output + y[yp:]
    return output

def treeMerge(heads, accum):
    currHead = 0
    while heads[currHead] is not None:
        accum = merge(heads[currHead], accum)
        heads[currHead] = None
        currHead = currHead + 1
    heads[currHead] = accum
    return heads

def legoSort(input):
    heads = [None] * int(math.log(len(input), 2) + 1)
    accum = []
    for i in input:
        # can be <= for speed at the cost of sort stability
        if len(accum) == 0 or i < accum[0]: 
            accum.insert(0,i)
        elif i >= accum[-1]:
            accum.append(i)
        else:
            heads = treeMerge(heads, accum)
            accum = [i]
    for i in heads:
        if i is not None:
            accum = merge(accum, i)
    return accum
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you got something similar to timsort or natural merge.

Comment: Yup, a natural merge that uses runs forwards and backwards.

Answer (score 1):

It is rather boring to research unknown code written in unknown language. You'd rather find it here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort at the end of Analysis

Comment: It's Python. :/ That's not an unknown language at all.

Comment: Agree, though up-voted as it's definitely a variation of merge sort, and seems like variation he refers to is what you might be doing. He also might be making a jab at you as python uses Timsort which involves merge sorting.

Comment: Yes, I know it is Python. I meant it is unknown for me. That is FOR ME it is hard to translate the program to algorithm.

Comment: It doesn't feel like mergesort to me (aside from, of course, merging lists); it doesn't have any recursive behavior. I see the resemblance to timsort; thanks for the tip. The big difference is that the algorithm's double-endedness allows for extracting reversed runs (or more complicated, something like 5 6 4 7 3 8 2 9 1 gets handled as a run), but the galloping procedure does look conceptually similar.

Comment: Well, it seems to be similar, though made without recursion. If I am wrong, perhaps i should delete the answer.

Comment: Actually, some further reading indicates this is a modification of the "natural merge sort". Means it's O(n log n) worst case, O(n) best case, and probably has reasonably good coefficients but the memory allocation might be as painful as array insertion, so it may just break even. Thanks! (Edit: Actually, I realized that I can eliminate the extra allocations in O(n) space...)

Comment: Undeleted my answer about similarity to timsort and natural merge. I agree though that it's definitely a variation of natural merge sort, and the bounds. Although, hard to say how it compares practically speaking to natural merge/Timsort.